# force a legend when there is no corresponding data

Tags: vega-lite

I'm hoping to get pointers for how to include an item in the legend despite the fact that it's not in the data---I tried to add it by way of sort, but that doesn't appear to work---[editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgYATgGtsUdui1qNkZEvjcAJoyXV9oCBEgBPBxqdQAZo2Rir+pB4WoyoqMgB6p7OeC6EyIHcWjZK6GIm0VDoAB6MsA5BzGIJOAAMAL5R0ZCKWnj6ANoe1V7c3IZaYMjZeOawPEpg3FRaaelVmZC2vaPweIxUYBR5rGmMAF7o88r5E9WweFuM8Esra5vbg5aohMrm9XuekJZWyGDU5sijvVZg7C5gVrtIyQZoQAC6zUqzUg2QK6Go1C0wl6gUsrCUDygsXigQAjqtMcwjlQ1FlcvkcMBCnhivoKtCnpYxEl3JMfH4AjhnohuMcEo9sXESlAkik0hl9vA0iLqciRrARQBGRn7JL1HBNTLOACiPWR4TEAJQYkIXlY4zBTkgADUvsa-GaLZLJgBlbjhADuiC2YBNTst2qgADluHgwIo-Y7zYHtZBQ+H-THQZlwYLIMUPkouWBqfNaSLIAAJaMWpTIWD5cpQjSqyBWLaYKkwihpVgVxpWvMhMIRQJAjpdHp9AZDEZjMk8vnwQvur0+xOl9Kqzzd0LhHM1Q7zE7LWCrCQXUfXW7lzGTpDTwt2rQO03JldONe9zfTL7oOYLN57g8bI47C9eX5QI52Qb1fSTZ1HwgZ8NzRaw3izd8fj+AEBxBVQoEvYDuQTCNuCje8oMFWC+25dDOm6XolH6ZQx3fMRxiwoCZ0CG87wDSBoNzIIezg7kDiOXczkPf8rg9U97kAq82PtQjOO40jX0xd9P0WH9zjE3ZmJk7k9WCNA-A4h8SN49cyKwhD3k+b4IlQwE2g6aScKgUDwMXIjl1M4JzM3Cih2o2jBmGBimKnFzbTkyCvK7MyX0CQSd1OfdNMuMATzuc9MPC1jcLDfD5JM2KfPigTt2OZLfyPOiMrPLEcsLPDI2irjvL4iznispDbN+f4HOBYxsuw3LXI9MCF0K4jivavzHKMAKRzokLRkY5yRsi29JpizJHDjEr+KgRKKo00S0tqqTBWcYbC30g0jK2lNokUuKDqmFTZnmdSRL-S5tIawJbsMo0Hue-aOpeRCbK2Oy+ootbryipdWum3z+zmyjhxo0dlonIaWJu-UgeMqadqtGIZoS8rhJS07jwkzKHjJnSIrciaWqtUGKe5N8Pq-SrUoGP7roBwnDWJ7boiU+DXms8sevsuG8d0qB2JBtrUfI9GFqxpbx1WpWItVlrOY1qAeY-T7v2+6qaPhkWDLFtWUdKs33otvmTp+wW7b00X7uN9WXc6mXuuh3q0PRn2VcRzyuOaSEIGrcogA). In this example, I want "Not helpful" to show up in the legend, despite the fact that it was not present in any responses.

I understand that this is somewhat against the whole visual encodings concept, but I think the use case is valid.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by specifying the scale domain:

```
"scale": {
  "domain": [
    "Extremely helpful",
    "Very helpful",
    "Somewhat helpful",
    "Not so helpful",
    "Not helpful"
  ]
}
```

The result looks like this ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-ty0bBtwobXvOgqQV23LIZ03S9Eo-TKEOz5iOMaF-hOgQXle3qQOBmZBB2UHcgcRybmcu7flcSqHvcv5nkxlq4ax7GEY+mLPq+iwfucQm7PREncpqwRoH4LE3gRnHLkRaEwe8nzfBEiGAm0HTiRhjrOjOIF4WBhnBMZq4kX25GUYMww0XRY4OZAzHSQZapyYEvEbqc26qZcYAHncx6ocFjGYYG2HhfhkVGQ+0XrsccWfnuVHJUeWLpbmWEhnObl5R5BXci8sEWVsVn-DZwLGGl6EZY507ATlDVtvl3HeLZRg+QOVEBaMtH2QNoVSfVbEEaa2JcSZa58SVCX7iJKUPJt1WBNp2p6SN8bRLJ407U+szzMpAlfpc6lnVpWq6bq113U1E3PGZcGWb8XUkUt56raB62NdtXlTaR-YUYO80jn1DG5hdP36blbanQDO0xcVKmCYlFViYKzj9ZOTnDWtar-fDgSPS+z3vq9ZUUZD53fTquOjdEUUtcD7UIeDiM89yYVrUznndojM0o3Nw6LRjmlQDLMNy81UCs0pHPxWTAwfTTvM6fzf3ucz3L6+z+3Gz+6shdjluy9b8si685nFqD1kQ87y1a65bHNImYDluUQA)):
[image]